# I cannot post to a user's Facebook Photo Album using my app's access token

Tags: facebook, image, http, url, facebook-graph-api

I am sending a POST request to `/FACEBOOK_ID/photos?access_toke=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`.  I already have `publish_stream` permission.  My goal is to post a photo into the user's photo album of my Application (Facebook creates an album for that app).

The result is:

```
{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}
```

OK, so I tried to use the `user_access_token` instead of my app's access token. But it says that it has "expired"?

I can't do either! What can I do? Ideally, I want to use the app's access token for all cases. That's because I can't just bring the user to the Facebook "allow" dialog everytime...

Posting a status update works fine (I use the app's access token), but it's only when I do photos that I run into this problem.

Note: I will give **500** bounty to whoever can answer this for me ASAP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you [obtain the user's access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), request the [`offline_access` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#extended_perms) to obtain a user access token that doesn't expire.  Store the token & use it in the POST to /.../photos.

Note that this is only a short-term fix as Facebook are [removing the `offline_access` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) on May 1 2012.  After that applications will have to call a new FB api to extend the life of an existing access token.